# What Is the Difference Between Wizard and Warlock in Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

One of Dumbledore's titles is "Chief Warlock of the Wizengamot".

**What is the difference between a Wizard and a Warlock in Potterverse?** As we don't see the term Warlock used often in the books, my impression is that a Warlock is somehow officially different from a Wizard.

Please no Wikipedia, HP Wikia, or dictionary.com answers. I'm looking for a canon-based¹ explanation.

¹<sub>Any of the ten *HP* books or a quote from JKR</sub>

Comment: I don't think that JKR ever gives a definition for either a Wizard or Warlock, but rather relies on the predefined notions that people have of them, and then builds on those notions. So I don't know that this can be properly answered without delving into dictionary descriptions of the words.

Comment: This question can definitely be answered without dictionary descriptions. :)

Comment: "Warlock" is used surprisingly often in HBP. At least four times, by my count.

Comment: “About five or six letters.”

Answer (score 38, accepted):

J. K. Rowling addresses her use of this in a footnote of the Warlock's Hairy Heart:

> The term "warlock" is a very old one.  Although it is sometimes used
>   as interchangeable with "wizards", it originally denoted one learned
>   in dueling and all martial magic.  It was also given as a title to
>   wizards who had performed feats of bravery, rather as Muggles were
>   sometimes knighted for acts of valor.  By calling the young wizard in
>   this story a warlock, Beedle indicates that he has already been
>   recognized as especially skillful at offensive magic.  These days
>   wizards use "warlock" in one of two ways: to describe a wizard of
>   unusally fierce appearance, or as a title denoting particular skill or
>   achievement.  Thus, Dumbledore himself was Chief Warlock of the
>   Wizengamot. - JKR

As you see elsewhere in her writings there are  numerous examples of Rowling using both words through the books (Chief Warlock of the Wizengamot, The Warlock's Hairy Heart, innumerable counts of *wizard*), but some excerpts definitely use the words interchangeably:

> Records show that witches and **wizards** in Europe were using flying
>   broomsticks as early as A.D. 962. A German illuminated manuscript of
>   this period shows three **warlocks** dismounting from their brooms with
>   looks of exquisite discomfort on their faces.

From Quidditch Through The Ages.

> Describe the circumstances that led to the formation of the
>   International Confederation of **Wizards** and explain why the **warlocks** of
>   Liechtenstein refused to join.

From the Order of the Phoenix (an exam question).

> Of course, the centuries-old trade in love potions shows that our
>   fictional **wizard** is hardly alone in seeking to control the
>   unpredictable course of love.

From the Warlock's Hairy Heart's postscript, about the man described as a warlock everywhere  else.

Comment: After having a search through the books, warlocks appear most often in official documents and bars.  I'm not sure if there's a link there.

Comment: I'm surprised you mention *The Warlock's Hairy Heart*, but don't go further with it. :)

Comment: I had a quick scan to see if she called him a warlock all the way through or if she interchanged like my two examples above, but as far as I could see it was solely warlock.  May have missed some examples though.

Comment: Well, if you feel like it, read it further. :)

Comment: Guess I found what you were hinting at, which amusingly also means my initial joke about official documents and bars is pretty much the actual truth!  I had read the story, but had not read the postscript.

Comment: I thought it would make a good universe-specific question. It's not general knowledge, but it applies *generally* to Potterverse, if that makes sense. I'm glad you decided to read further -- there's a lot of good canon in *Tales of Beedle the Bard* that a lot of people don't know about. +1 and accept -- thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Warlock appears to be a term used to describe famous wizards, or wizards that are noteworthy for courage.

Otherwise, there appears to be no difference at all.

Comment: Although not untrue, this is lacking any sort of reference to back it up.