# Is there a gender-neutral term for witches and wizards?

Tags: harry-potter

When writing questions and answers here about the *Harry Potter* series, I often need a word for "someone who's not a Muggle". People often refer to "the wizarding world" as opposed to the Muggle word, so "**wizard**" would be one choice - but it seems slightly sexist to exclude witches in that way. On the other hand, "**witch or wizard**" is a bit cumbersome, much longer than the simple word "Muggle".

Is there a sensible word to use which is neither sexist nor cumbersome, that makes a good equivalent to "Muggle"? What would JK Rowling say to fill in a sentence such as this:

> Muggles use technology, while [...] use magic.

Comment: hmm, _my_ vote would be for this question to stay open and [the other one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9227/54827) be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @RedCaio Up to you, if you want to VTRO. I'm abstaining for obvious reasons ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## "Wizard" can be used for males and females

Dumbledore uses the term "wizards" to refer to both males and females.

> HERMIONE: Please believe us.
>
> DUMBLEDORE: I do, Miss Granger.
>   But the word of three 13-year-old
>   **wizards** will convince few others
>
> <sub>*- Prisoner of Azkaban (film)*</sub>

The shrunken heads also use "wizards" to refer to both males and females when Ron and Hermione try to follow Harry, who is under the invisibility cloak, into a tavern at Hogsmeade.

> HERMIONE: Harry!
>
> SHRUNKEN HEAD 1: No underage **wizards** allowed in today!
>
> SHRUNKEN HEAD 2: Shut the [...] door!
>
> HERMIONE: So rude.
>
> RON: Thick heads.
>
> <sub>*- Prisoner of Azkaban (film)*</sub>

Ron uses "wizard" to describe a group of presumably mixed gender individuals.

> Harry -- this is a Pocket Sneakoscope. If there's someone untrustworthy around, it's supposed to light up and spin. Bill says it's rubbish sold for **wizard tourists** and isn't reliable, because it kept lighting up at dinner last night. But he didn't realize Fred and George had put beetles in his soup.
>
> <sub>*- Prisoner of Azkaban (book)*</sub>

In all these situations the term "wizards" was used to describe a group of males and females. It is presumably acceptable to do so as it is unlikely that Dumbledore, a polite and respectable person, would use the wrong word.

---

#### That said, there are other terms that are also gender neutral, such as:

- "magician"
- "magical"
- "magic folk"
- "the wizarding world"
- "wand carrier"

More specific, but still gender neutral terms include:

- "aurors"
- "students"
- "hogwartians"

#### The term "wizarding" seems to be fairly common

From *Prisoner of Azkaban (book)*:

- "the wizarding world"
- "wizarding village"
- "wizarding newspaper"
- "Gringotts Wizarding Bank"
- > "So Harry had had no word from any of his **wizarding friends** for five long weeks"

Comment: Is this quote from the book or the film?

Comment: CAN CONFIRM, WIZARDS in book.

Comment: @randal'thor I've specified when I'm referencing the book and when I'm referencing the film.

Comment: And before the SJWs start, no, this is not sexist against females. If anything it's sexist against males because there is no term for male wizards that doesn't also include women.

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Answer (score 6):

The gender-neutral term **"wand carrier"** is used on occasion in the *Harry Potter* books, and so that is canon.

Speaking outside of *Harry Potter* specifics for a moment, I always assumed that **wizard** ***was*** a gender-neutral term, and that the male and female terms were **warlock** and **witch**, respectively.

> Warlock (noun)
>
> 1. **a man who professes or is supposed to practice magic or sorcery; a male witch; sorcerer.**
> 2. a fortuneteller or conjurer.

([Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/warlock))

Comment: That's odd: I always thought wizard was the male equivalent of witch, and warlock was something slightly different and gender-neutral. But this sounds like a question for ELU rather than SFF...

Comment: In HP, a Warlock is a very specific term, and not one that is simply interchangeable with "wizard"

Comment: @Richard : That's why I say *"outside of Harry Potter specifics"*.  :-)

Comment: @randal'thor : Most dictionary definitions of wizard are gender neutral while warlock is gendered.  (E.g. [Wizard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wizard), from the same source.). But I definitely agree that wizard has taken on a male connotation.

Comment: As a further aside, in diablo 3 the magical character is a Wizard for either gender :).

Comment: +1, but RedCaio's answer is more complete, so I'm afraid you probably won't get the tick :-)

Comment: @randal'thor : That's fine.  I would have added more, but RedCaio started building up a very thorough answer, and so I +1'ed his and left it at that. :-)