# What would a non-binary or genderfluid magical person be called in the Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter

I think it is safe to assume that magical otherkin would not have a problem as they would be able to express themselves by becoming Animagi, but what would we call a magical person of unconventional gender?

I doubt they would be happy being called a witch or a wizard, as both terms presume a strict gender binary, so what term would they use?

Please note that this question is asked with tongue firmly in cheek, but I do wonder if any thought has been put into this type of question by either the fans or JK herself.

Comment: Simple: You call them what they request to be called. That goes for every enby or genderfluid person, IRL or in fiction.

Comment: I mean, is there a third term apart from witch or wizard?

Comment: As far as I know, a "mage" can have an integer or non-integer gender.

Comment: Wizard is used for both males and females.

Comment: @Mithrandir "Hogwarts School of _Wizardry_ and _Witchcraft_" - seems like there's a distinction.

Comment: Is that the case in the Potterverse Mithrandir?  I do not recall any of the female characters being called wizards, but I may have missed an instance in which that happened.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - see Rand's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They'd be called a wizard.

As seen in the answers to [Is there a gender-neutral term for witches and wizards?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117706/31394), "wizard" is a gender-neutral term which can be used for both male and female magic users, and therefore presumably also for those of non-binary gender.

There are also terms such as "wand carrier" or "magic user", but these are more clumsy and awkward. Just go with "wizard" - that term seems to work for everyone, regardless of gender.

Comment: Why "wizard", and not "witch"? That's sexist, isn't it?

Comment: @Gallifreyan No, there's nothing sexist about "wizard", because it's a **gender-neutral** term. A witch just means a female wizard.

Comment: But there clearly exist a distinction between the two terms, i.e. when they're both used, one is used for males and the other for females. I don't remember a witch being called a "wizard" to her face (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @Gallifreyan - 'warlock' and 'witch' are the gender specific terms. 'wizard' is neutral.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - yes. A female wizard is called a wizard to her face; see the duplicate link.

Comment: Maybe it is like "actor".  Even though "actress" exists, the term actor can be treated as gender neutral.

Comment: @Mithrandir If you're referring to Dumbledore's words, then he uses "wizards" as collective noun. Has a witch ever been called a wizard?