# Are there any transgender or non-binary characters, magical or normal, in all the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter

Including main books, side-books, films, video games, tie-ins, etc., are there any instances of any character in the expanded Harry Potter universe **long term/permanently** changing their gender and/or identifying as neither male nor female?

Note the permanency qualification: so temporarily Polyjuicing or metamorphosing into another gender does not qualify—this should be a major life-change rather than an espionage tool.

Comment: Since you are asking about transgender characters, I assume you are talking about characters changing their *sex,* correct? In real life, the *gender* of both transgender and cisgender people is not typically something that is or can be changed.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163351/what-would-a-non-binary-or-genderfluid-magical-person-be-called-in-the-potterver

Comment: @Adamant Some people are (or claim to be) gender-fluid.  There is no set consensus that says that gender identity is immutable.  While this is neither a scientifically nor politically resolved issue, I have not yet met someone who believes that sex can be changed while simultaneously believing that every person is permanently confined to one fixed gender identity.

Comment: @Misha - Thus the use of the term "typically." Genderfluid people exist, clearly, but most people are not genderfluid and have pretty stable gender identities. In any case, the question writer seems to equate changing sex with changing gender, when they are not the same thing. Since the question title asks about transgender people, but the question asks about people who change their gender, some clarification could be useful.

Comment: Also, the body seems to be talking about people who change their sex or external sexual presentation, which is also not a requirement to be trans. Not every transgender person has undergone gender affirmation therapy, so if they are only asking about trans folks who have undergone the fictional equivalent, that would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Considering the username you've chosen, I suspect you already knew that the answer to this question was "no".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Given how little input JKR has into the new games, I don't think her opinion (one way or another) is especially relevant.

Answer (score 6):

In a word, no. There are no overtly transgender (or non-binary) human characters in any Harry Potter property, books, video game or any other tie-in materials.

There was a rumour that *[Harry Potter: Legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogwarts_Legacy)* would have a trans character, but this seems to have morphed into allowing you to create a trans-*ish* character by choosing female characteristics (voice, etc) for your male character and vice-versa. It remains to be seen whether any of the minor characters will be transgender, but probably not.

> As a result, some members of the Hogwarts Legacy development team have
> fought to make the game as inclusive as possible, pushing for the
> character customization and even for a transgender character to be
> added. There was resistance from management at first, the people
> familiar with the project said, but currently the character
> customization is included in the game. A Warner Bros. spokesperson
> declined to comment.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter Video Game Will Allow Transgender Characters](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-03-02/harry-potter-video-game-will-allow-for-transgender-characters)</sup></sub>

Comment: Discussion cleaned up. Many sources, including Wikipedia, indicate that transgendered is an old fashioned term that is now discouraged to be used or even purely deprecated. I think we should avoid it here.