# Does J.K. Rowling distinguish between a sorcerer and a wizard?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, wizards, witches

I'm not sure if "wizard" and "sorcerer" are just the same in the Harry Potter universe. I can remember Harry saying in a movie: "Dumbledore is the greatest sorcerer of all time". And I have read somewhere that wizards and witches stand on the same level. Wizards are sometimes used to describe "boys and girls" or "mankind" while witches are only for girls. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Is the word "sorcerer" is just another term to describe a wizard/witch? Or are they different from each other?

Comment: Wizards are both, witches are just girl

Comment: [What is the difference between Witchcraft and Wizardry in HP?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163910/what-is-the-difference-between-witchcraft-and-wizardry-in-hp)

Comment: [Is there a gender-neutral term for witches and wizards?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117706/is-there-a-gender-neutral-term-for-witches-and-wizards)

Comment: @Valorum Good question. Yes. Both Sorcerer, and Wizard are gender neutral terms for a magic user. Another gender neutrat term is Mage.

Comment: Well a wizards staff has a nob on its end

Comment: Voldemort calls himself greatest sorcerer in the chamber of secrets

Comment: Read Terry Pratchett's "Sorcery". Voldemort would have **** himself if he had ever met a sorcerer. No sorcerers in the Harry Potter books fortunately.

Comment: @gnasher729 No, that was a *sourcerer*. Big difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There appears to be no difference between wizard and sorcerer, save that one *tends* to be used in a more formal and historical context.

> They shared a wish, a hope, a dream,
>   They hatched a daring plan
>   To educate **young sorcerers**
>   Thus Hogwarts School began.
>
> <sub><sup>HP and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

It's also used (by the author) when it works as a form of alliteration, hence why there are *Scandinavian sorcerers*, and why Celestine Warbeck is a

> "Singing sorceress"

Comment: And in America, of course, people like Kierkegaard, Plato, Hegel, and Jung are also sorcerers, though I doubt they’d be considered wizards.